# Problema en composer install --prefer-dist YII2

Tags: php, yii2, composer, backend

Presento un problema cuando ejecuto el comando `composer install --prefer-dist` en el directorio de un proyecto en YII2. El error es el siguiente:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base dev-master -> satisfiable by kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base[dev-master].
> - kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base dev-master requires yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4 @dev -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4[2.0.x-dev, dev-dmirogin-patch-1, dev-master, 1.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Mi composer.json es el siguiente

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "execut/yii2-widget-bootstraptreeview": "dev-master",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
        "githubjeka/yii2-gui-rbac": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-builder": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-field-range": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-icons": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-label-inplace": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-money": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "1.0.1",
        "kartik-v/yii2-nav-x": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-slider": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-tabs-x": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop": "@dev",
        "miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "dev-master",
        "warrence/yii2-kartikgii": "dev-master",
        "edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module": "^1.1.2",
        "2amigos/yii2-gallery-widget": "~1.0",
        "unclead/yii2-multiple-input": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Mi versión de PHP es la siguiente:

> ```
> ~ $ php --version
> ```
>
> PHP 7.2.6-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
>   (built: Jun 11 2018 14:59:25) ( NTS ) 
> Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP
>   Group Zend Engine v3.2.0, 
> Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.6-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 
> Copyright 
>   (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Mi versión de composer es ésta:

> ```
> ~ $ composer --version
> ```
>
> Composer version 1.6.4 2018-04-13 12:04:24

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionar el problema?

Comment: Este enlace lo puede ayudar https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-builder/issues/10

Comment: Las librerías que menciona las debes tener sobre dev-master ya que las necesita porque trabaja sobre esas versiones

Answer (score 0):

Viendo tu composer.json,te recomiendo utilizar https://asset-packagist.org/ como repositorio para los paquetes bower, npm de todos tus proyectos, ademas se revisar las extensiones y ver su versiones estables de lanzamiento si no tiene ninguna siempre coloca '@dev' para bajar la ultima versión de desarrollo de cada uno de los paquetes, ademas de usar composer-installers-extender para cambiar la ruta de los activos.

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^1.1",        
        "yiisoft/yii2": "^2.0.20",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "@dev",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "^2.1.0",
        "execut/yii2-widget-bootstraptreeview": "@dev",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
        "githubjeka/yii2-gui-rbac": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-builder": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-field-range": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-icons": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-label-inplace": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-money": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "1.0.1",
        "kartik-v/yii2-nav-x": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-slider": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-tabs-x": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop": "@dev",
        "miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "@dev",
        "warrence/yii2-kartikgii": "@dev",
        "edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module": "^1.1.2",
        "2amigos/yii2-gallery-widget": "~1.0",
        "unclead/yii2-multiple-input": "@dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "^3.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.1.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.1.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "fxp-asset": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-types": ["bower-asset", "npm-asset"],
        "installer-paths": {
            "vendor/bower/{$name}/": ["type:bower-asset"],
            "vendor/npm/{$name}/": ["type:npm-asset"]
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ]    
}
```